# sysfs: free to use struct device platform_data field?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver, sysfs

Summary: is the `platform_data` field of `struct device` free to use in a device driver module?

I am creating a very simple sysfs entry for my character device driver module to allow me to control an internal variable (because I know using `ioctl()` and the `proc` filesystem are deprecated.) I call `class_create()` to make a class in `/sys/class/` and then `device_create()` to make a new device entry. Then I call `device_create_file()` to set up my load and store routines for the driver. I want to lock my driver in these routines. I have a mutex in my driver's main structure. Can I use the `platform_data` field to store a pointer to this structure like I would the `private_data` field of `struct file` in the module's `open()` routine or is this reserved? It's set to NULL after `device_create` so it would appear OK but I don't know for sure.

What I'd like to do is:

```
struct mymodule mymod; // main module structure, has a mutex called lockmx

static ssize_t mydev_store_val(struct device *dev,
                               struct device_attribute *attr,
                               const char *buf,size_t count)
{
   struct mymodule *mymodp=(struct mymodule*)dev->platform_data;

   if(mutex_lock_interruptible(&mymodp->lockmx))
      return 0;

   // get data from buf

   mutex_unlock(&mymodp->lockmx);

   return count;
}

DEVICE_ATTR(mydeva,S_IWUSR|S_IRUGO,NULL,mydev_store_val);

static int __init modinit(void)
{
   ...

   dev_t dev; // alloc'ed already

   myclass=class_create(THIS_MODULE,"myclass");
   mydev=device_create(myclass,NULL,dev,NULL,"mydev");
   mydev->platform_data=&mymod;
   device_create_file(mydev,&dev_attr_mydeva);

   ...
}
```

So this will create the entry `/sys/class/myclass/mydev/mydeva` which can be written to. If the `platform_data` field is available then I can avoid using globals. But if it moves under me my kernel is going to oops at best and probably panic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a pointer can be stored in the `drvdata` field (which has been cleverly hidden so that you will not see it if you look at the definition of `struct device`).

Initialize it through the fourth parameter of `device_create`, and read it with `dev_get_drvdata`:

```c
mydev = device_create(myclass, NULL, dev, &mymod, "mydev");
...
struct mymodule *mymodp = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I'm working from LDD3 (I wish they'd write a 4th ed. as learning curve is steep.) Looking at kernel code there is an analogous dev_set_drvdata() which sets up dev->p->driver_data if it hasn't been already. Handy to know.